# Resultset(java.sql) object doesn't fetch data after generating resultset once

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am making a component that has a text field and a list where the keytyped in text field is listened and accordingly resultset is generated and added to the list.
It doesnt work when i erase the typed keys, and type new keys. The resultset is not fetched accordingly again. What to do?

code:

```
    @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {

  searchstring = searchstring + ke.getKeyChar();
  System.out.println(searchstring);
    try {            
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

                System.out.println(ex.toString());

          }

        try {
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+databasename,username,password);

                Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

                String s = "select "+columnname+" from "+tablename+" where "+columnname+" like "+"'"+searchstring+"%"+"'";
                System.out.println(s);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(s);
                list.removeAll();
                while(rs.next()){

                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                    list.add(rs.getString(1));
                }

        }catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.println(ex.toString());

        }



}
```

Comment: do you "clear" your searchstring after you erase the typed keys?

Comment: Have you actually *debugged* your code ? :)

Comment: Close the resources properly.use prepared statement .. Handle BackSpace char , dont just add to searchString .. if possible use Stringbuffer/StringBuilder based on your need

Comment: I resolved the issue. Thanks for showing interest in the question. 
I now handled the keyreleased event and at everykeyrelease the serachstring is updated by using getText() method of textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You are continuously appending typed characters to search string:

```
searchstring = searchstring + ke.getKeyChar();
```

Because of this search will keep changing as you type - both when you type, use back space to erase the field. At the end `searchstring` will not match anything you have in the database. That is why the list does not change!

Instead of modifying `searchstring`, create another variable for appending the key char and use that value in the where clause of the query.

Note: This way of appending user input to the query opens up your app for SQL injection attacks. You should use prepared statements to protect your app against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I resolved the issue. Thanks for showing interest in the question. I now handled the keyreleased event and at everykeyrelease the serachstring is updated by using getText() method of textfield.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your searchString is getting polluted due to all the key chars or backspace you are adding to it. so replace

```
searchstring = searchstring + ke.getKeyChar();
```

with

```
searchstring = yourTextField.getText() + ke.getKeyChar();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I resolved the issue. Thanks for showing interest in the question. I now handled the keyreleased event and at everykeyrelease the serachstring is updated by using getText() method of textfield

Comment: Great ... have fun coding :)

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev. You too! :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.Posting my new answer code as none of the answers given here before this answer are fully correct and for reference of others who may face same problem in future.
I now handled the **keyReleased** event **instead of keyTyped event**. And at every keyrelease the serachstring is updated by using **getText() method** of textfield. The **getKeyChar() contaminates the searchstring** because it traces the backspace characters too.
The component i am using this logic for is a component designed using JFC for desktop software, which works similar to google's search textbox that fetches data using AJAX.Just the difference here is that this is a Desktop software and not a dynamic webpage. I did not find any such an inbuilt component in JFC .So i used a JTextfield component and awt List component togather.And it works perfectly fine now.
Any criticism for the code is most welcome.

code:

```
     @Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {



        searchstring = enterstring.getText();
        char[] searcharray = searchstring.toCharArray();


         if(searcharray.length==0){

            list.setVisible(false);

         }
         else{

             list.setVisible(true);
         }

       System.out.println(searchstring.length());
    try {            
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

                System.out.println(ex.toString());

          }

        try {
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+databasename,username,password);

                Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

                String s = "select "+columnname+" from "+tablename+" where "+columnname+" like "+"'"+searchstring+"%"+"'";
                System.out.println(s);
                list.removeAll();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(s);

                while(rs.next()){

                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                    list.add(rs.getString(1));
                }

        }catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.println(ex.toString());

        }

}
```